# How does this circuit with inverters work?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, inverter, cmos, gain

[image]

What this does this circuit do?  I suspect it is an amplifier, but don't know how it amplifies.

For example *Inv 5* and *Inv 6* are connected in parallel with reverse sides but there is a wire between them, wouldn't that wire just cancel whatever their function is and they are there for ?

How do *Inv 7* and *Inv 8* affect gain of the circuit if this actually is an amplifier ?

Some information :

Assuming size of Inv7 and Inv8 3 times other inverters and I(inverter 6) =100uA and input CM equals to voltage of Point A.

Find current of other transistors Va=Vdd/2=1.5

Comment: Where did you get the circuit? What other information was provided along with the schematic? Why do you care what it does...what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: A similar but simpler circuit is the "Nauta gm-cell", read about it here: https://ris.utwente.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/6771395/cmos_transconductance.pdf  then learn from the article how such a circuit is analyzed and apply the same technique to this circuit.

Comment: this is an example from a question our professor gave to his students in recent years. i've updated the question to add some more details.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you verymuch can you explain it please ? i have the exam in two days so no sufficient time to read whole article.

Comment: Why is there a short circuit across Inv5 and Inv6? If you want my opinion, it's a nonesense circuit. Good luck in the exam though.

Comment: If you don't have enough time to read the article and understand the question then you should ask your instructor to delay the exam, or possibly you should accept a grade of "Incomplete" for the course and finish up next semester.

Comment: It has some unstable tendencies from the inner loop short, but it has very high gain and imbalance errors in gm can be reduced by precision R ratios  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxduO.png  looks terrible.